# Checking if a relation is a function

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The question:

> Define a relation $P$ from $\mathbb{R}^+$ to $\mathbb{R}$ as follows:
>   For all real numbers $x$ and $y$ with $x>0$, \begin{align}
>  \left(x,y\right)\in P\:\:\text{means that}\:\:x=y^2. \end{align} Is
>   $P$ a function?

I would say it is, but is that right? The whole "$\mathbb{R}^+$ to $\mathbb{R}$" part is throwing me off because I can't imagine its relation to $P$.

Thanks,

Comment: $(1,1) \in P$ but $(1,-1)\in P$

Comment: The "$\mathbb{R}^+$ to $\mathbb{R}$" part means that $x$ needs to be positive and $y$ needs to be a real number.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom 1 is positive and $1,-1$ are real numbers.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom If that is the case, then $x>0$, and $y$ is always greater than $0$ anyway because it's squared and an element of the set of all reals?

Comment: @bd1251252 see Vargas' comment

Comment: @bd1251252: But it is not true that $y$ is always greater than $0$. For example, to reuse Vladimir's example, $(x,y)=(1,-1)$ is in $P$ because $1=(-1)^2$.

Comment: The point of specifying "from $\mathbb R^+$ to $\mathbb R$" is such that it does _not_ prevent $P$ from being a function that, for example, there is no $y$ such that $(-5,y)\in P$. Being a function only requires that every $x$ _in the specified domain_ have a (unique) corresponding $y$.

Comment: The title implies that the problem involves defining some relation $P$, but the relation $P$ is in fact already defined in the question.  If you're going to ask other people to do your homework for you, please at least take the trouble to put an accurate title on your post.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I totally understand that, what I meant to say (I apologize, I was not clear), is that the entire term "$y^2$" is positive. Vargas is right, I see that now. Thanks guys :) And sorry this actually got a bad vote. It was just a question in my textbook, I literally copied it down exactly as it was written.

Comment: @WillO Thanks for all of your "excellent" help. In fact, this isn't my homework, I've already done all of that and I'm two weeks ahead in courses that just started *today*. This is a problem I'm working on in a chapter of another book -- one of many -- so don't go telling *me* that I'm out to get others to do *my* homework. I'm really tired of people overreacting on this forum over that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there have been some misunderstandings (I think) in the comments, I will post an answer:

A function $f:\mathbb R^+ \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ is a subset of $\mathbb R^+ \times \mathbb R$ of ordered pairs such that for each $x\in \mathbb R^+$ there is a $y\in \mathbb R$ such that $(x,y)\in f$; and if $(x,y)\in f$ and $(x,z)\in f$ then $y=z$.

But since your relation $P$ contains both $(1,1)$ and $(1,-1)$, then $P$ can't be a function.

Comment: Thanks :) Please see my comment above also. Your post makes sense.